# quick search autocomplete not working on civi 4.6.20 drupal 7.50

Tags: 4.6, quicksearch

After the last minor update, my colleague pointed out that quick search auto complete is not operating. I don't find any similar issues in stackexchange or jira, and couldn't reproduce it on the 4.7 demo site. I am seeing a failure in the browser on this resource:

403 error
https://domain.org/civicrm/ajax/rest?entity=contact&action=getquick&json=%7B%22name%22%3A%22asdf%22%2C%22field_name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22table_name%22%3A%22cc%22%7D

Answer (score 1):

This was a hosting issue. ModSecurity rules had to be edited. Not a 4.6 update issue at all.